# In Adobe Illustrator CS6 how to add a smilie or a tick mark into a layer name field?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layers

In Adobe Illustrator CS6 how do I add a smilie or a tick mark into a layer name field?

Comment: It may be just me but I don't get what you are asking...This is a one line question and it probably needs some detail put into it and a screenshot of what you want to achieve.

Comment: Here is a great website from where you can copy cool smiley symbols. [http://www.copypastecharacter.com/symbols](http://www.copypastecharacter.com/symbols)

Answer (score 1):

The same way you get any other character into the layer name: you type it. And, as with any other text, if you cannot literally *type* a certain character, you can always copy it from somewhere else and paste it into the name.

[image: I ♥ this layer]

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer to my own question. These items can be found in Show Character Viewer menu at top of screen.

Comment: Do you mind going into better detail?  This could help someone else in the future